# Why is this 'for' loop not working?

Tags: javascript, oop, for-loop

I have a Javascript object called TweenManager which contains an array of Tween objects. The TweenManager should call the step() method on each tween in the 'tweens' array and all the tweens should run at the same time.

However, what's actually happening is that the TweenManager only runs one tween at a time, and doesn't start the next one until the previous tween is complete.

Here's the code for the tween manager

UPDATE: It might make more sense to [look at it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5FLQ/549/)

```
//Manage all tweens
function TweenManager(){

    this.tweens = new Array();
    this.timer;

    this.start = function(){
        this.timer = setInterval(this.run, 1, this);
    }

    // Loop through all tweens and call the step method
    this.run = function(myself){

        console.log(myself.tweens.length);

        // stop the interval if the tween array is empty
        if(myself.tweens.length == 0){
            clearInterval(myself.timer)
        }

        // loop through all tweens and call the step() method
            // !! Here's there the problem appears to be
        for(i = 0; i < myself.tweens.length; i++){

            thisTween = myself.tweens[i]        
            console.log(thisTween.element.attr('id'));  
            thisTween.step() // if I remove this, the line above logs the id's as expected

            // clean up if the tween is complete
            if(thisTween.t == thisTween.d){
                myself.tweens.splice(i, 1);
            }

        }

    }


    this.addTween = function(b,c,d,element,suffix, decimal){
        this.tweens.push( new Tween(b,c,d,element,suffix, decimal) )
    }

}
```

The problem appears to be in the for loop. I have a hunch that this might have something to do with passing in `this` in the `setInterval`, although it's just a hunch, I don't understand what the problem could be. I get confused with variable scopes and whatnot.

Here's the Tween Object (Yup, ripped off form Robert Penner)

```
// Tween a number, add a suffix and insert it into an element
function Tween(b, c, d, element, suffix, decimal){

    this.t = 0;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.b = b;
    this.element = element;
    this.suffix = suffix;

    this.step = function(){

        if(this.t != this.d){

            this.t += 1 
            var flip = 1
            if (this.c < 0) {
                flip *= -1
                this.c *= -1
            }
            i = flip * (-Math.exp(-Math.log(this.c)/this.d * (this.t-this.d)) + this.c + 1) + this.b

            if(!decimal){
                this.element.html(Math.round(i) + this.suffix)
            }else{
                output = (Math.round(i * 10) / 10 + this.suffix)
                formattedOutput = ( output - Math.round(output) == 0 ) ? output + ".0" : output;
                this.element.html(formattedOutput)
            }

        }   
    }

}
```

And here's the implementation

```
tweenManager = new TweenManager();
tweenManager.addTween(0,80,300, $("#el1"), "&deg;", false)
tweenManager.addTween(0,60,400, $("#el2"), "&#8217;", false)
tweenManager.addTween(0,12.5,300, $("#el3"), "", true)
tweenManager.start()
```

As always, any help, hinting or nudging the the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use setInterval as some sort of fork() function which means that you should moving it from where it is to put it on the step itself so that you call:

```
setInterval(thisTween.step, 1, ...
```

That is how you can make your tweens run in fake 'parallel'.

However what I really think you want is the new [HTML5 Web Workers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/) feature; I think that is for exactly this kind of activity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. The step method belongs to the Tween object. Are you saying I should get rid of the TweenManager all together? Also, WebWorkers would be great, but this has to work in IE 6&7.

Comment: You said that "the TweenManager only runs one tween at a time, and doesn't start the next one until the previous tween is complete" Well that is because you are not running the step function in its own interval. If you want to do that then you probably want to wrap the execution of that function in a setTimeout("thisTween.step()", 1); and go from there. That way all the steps will execute in parallel and they will only happen once per step interval.